# Duplicate carriage return when using read() of BufferedReader

Tags: java, input, bufferedreader, readline

When using read() from BufferedReader, when I press enter after typing input, the first input is taken but the next input statement is also executed, before I can type input for the next statement.

```java
char c = (char)br.read();
String S = br.readLine();
```

If I type a character and press enter, then `c` stores that character but `S` stores "" and it does not ask me to input `S`. It's as if Java automatically presses enter for the string input.

Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: `read` reads a single character, but you have typed two, the character and the return character. So the `readLine` reads the return character, which is terminating an empty line.

Comment: In any case there is no duplicate carriage return anywhere in your question.